# why we call the stateless bean as a session bean, why not session-less bean

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

In my understanding, session always means stateful. think about the servlet session object,

think about the cookie. if session is stateless, I think we don't need the session at all.

In the jee world, a kind of EJB called stateless session bean,

so, why we call a stateless bean as a "session bean" ?

Answer (score 3):

Because in the long ago there was a company called Weblogic. That company had a product called [Tengah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_WebLogic_Server). Then (Weblogic) was acquired by BEA (and Tengah was renamed Weblogic), and then BEA was acquired by Oracle.

Anyway, there are two types of Session Beans; stateless (or stateful) [session bean](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs100/ejb/understanding.html);

> Stateless Session Beans
>
> Stateful Session Beans
>
> Entity Beans
>
> Message-Driven Beans

Answer (score 0):

> so, why we call a stateless bean as a "session bean" ?

In this context "session" means [unit of work](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/transactions.html#transactions-basics-uow), the period of time the business transaction executes. For Stateless and Singleton this period matches with the request/response cycle. 
In Stateless and Singleton beans, a new session is opens when a new request arrives, and it lives until the response it sent back to the client. (session-per-request pattern)

With Stateful Session bean the business transaction (session) has the possibility to live during several client requests. (session-per-conversation pattern)